# Docker copy command failed?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I try to add to docker file, i simplified to very short one, that show the issue.

Simple Dockerfile - ddtest

```
FROM maven AS testdocker

COPY . /server
WORKDIR /server/admin

RUN mkdir target; echo "hello world" > ./target/test.txt
RUN pwd
RUN ls -la ./target/  

COPY ./target/test.txt /test.txt

CMD ["/usr/bin/java", "-jar", "/server.jar"]
```

Building with command docker build . -f ddtest

Execution log:

```
docker build . -f ddtest
Sending build context to Docker daemon  245.8kB
Step 1/8 : FROM maven AS testdocker
 ---> e85864b4079a
Step 2/8 : COPY . /server
 ---> e6c9c6d55be1
Step 3/8 : WORKDIR /server/admin
 ---> Running in d30bab5d6b6b
Removing intermediate container d30bab5d6b6b
 ---> 7409cbc70fac
Step 4/8 : RUN mkdir target; echo "hello world" > ./target/test.txt
 ---> Running in ad507dfc604b
Removing intermediate container ad507dfc604b
 ---> 0d69df30d041
Step 5/8 : RUN pwd
 ---> Running in 72becb9ae3ba
/server/admin
Removing intermediate container 72becb9ae3ba
 ---> 7bde9ccae4c6
Step 6/8 : RUN ls -la ./target/
 ---> Running in ceb5c222f3c0
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug  9 05:50 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Aug  9 05:50 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   12 Aug  9 05:50 test.txt
Removing intermediate container ceb5c222f3c0
 ---> 3b4dbcb794ad
Step 7/8 : COPY ./target/test.txt /test.txt
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder015566471/target/test.txt: no such file or directory
```

copy to destination docker test.txt failed, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `ls` command you invoked is running inside an intermediate container, which is not your host. So according to your `WORKDIR` you're listing files inside `/server/admin/target` of your container.

As the output of `ls` shows, this `test.txt` file is already inside your image

`COPY src dst` command copies a file/directory from your host to your image, and it seems that you don't have any file named `test.txt` inside `./target` directory of your host.

Comment: Please note that first you did a `COPY . /server`, then according to your `WORKDIR /server/admin` and `ls ./target` commands, your `test.txt` file is inside `./admin/target` directory inside your host. So you must do `COPY ./admin/target/test.txt whatever-destination` to point to this file.